# What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to make an image bigger and smaller on a click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make an image bigger when I click on a link but it won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a, large').click(function(){
    $("img").animate({width: "300px"});

  });

  $('a, small').click(function(){
    $("img").animate({width: "75px"});
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<center>
  <img src="TCRlogo.png"/></br>
  <a href="#" id="large">Large</a> - <a href="#" id="small">Small</a>
</center>
```

Comment: `$('#small')` prefix `#` for id-selector. See https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/rznzfc52/

Comment: There are brackets missing at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. It should be like #id.
Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a#large').click(function(){
    $("img").animate({width: "300px"});

  });

  $('a#small').click(function(){
    $("img").animate({width: "75px"});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
<img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300"/></br>
<a href="#" id="large">Large</a> - <a href="#" id="small">Small</a>
</center>
```

Comment: id can do no need of a only #large and #small can do

Comment: There are (still) brackets missing at the end.

Comment: @NikhilGhuse yes your are right ID is unique in dom so no need of 'a' in it.

Comment: You answered my question, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try the Following:

```
$('#small').click(function(){ 
  ... 
  });
```

and

```
$('#large').click(function(){ 
 ... 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

[check demo](https://jsfiddle.net/niks2060/rznzfc52/1/)

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#large').click(function(){
   $("img").animate({width: "300px"});    
   });

    $('#small').click(function(){
      $("img").animate({width: "75px"});
   });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<center>
<img src="TCRlogo.png"/></br>
<a href="#" id="large">Large</a> - <a href="#" id="small">Small</a>
</center>
```

Comment: share jsfiddle okk

Comment: There are (still) brackets missing at the end.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#large').click(function(){
  $("img").animate({width: "300px"});
  });
 $('#small').click(function(){
  $("img").animate({width: "75px"});
 });
});
```

Comment: A bracket is (still) missing at the end.

Comment: It was } or ) in last line, but it is present, now.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#large').click(function(){
    $(".img1").animate({width: "300px"});
 });

$('#small').click(function(){
    $(".img1").animate({width: "70px"});
});
```

Comment: Good idea not to update all images, but the HTML has to be changed for this, too.